# Install Drupal 8 on MAMP: can't detect version of Apache

Tags: 8

I'm trying to install Drupal 8 on my mac using MAMP Pro. I get this error message when Drupal tries to verify I have the proper configuration:

```
Apache Version:
Due to the settings for ServerTokens in httpd.conf, it is impossible to accurately 
determine the version of Apache running on this server. The reported value is 
Apache, to run Drupal without mod_rewrite, a minimum version of 2.2.16 is needed.
```

I have the latest version of MAMP Pro which is running 2.2.29.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Drupal uses Apache's [`ServerTokens`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#servertokens) in [`system_requirements()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21system%21system.install/function/system_requirements/8) to determine the version number. You currently have that set to "Prod", which just reveals "Apache" as the token, without any version number.

For Drupal to detect the major and minor versions, plus revision, you need to update the config setting to one of:

- **Full** - Server sends (e.g.): *Server: Apache/2.4.2 (Unix) PHP/4.2.2 MyMod/1.2*.
- **Min** - Server sends (e.g.): *Server: Apache/2.4.2*.
- **OS** - Server sends (e.g.): *Server: Apache/2.4.2 (Unix)*.

Comment: Located '/applications/MAMP/config/apache/extra/httpd-default.conf' if you use MAMP on a Mac. It's set to Full and I still get the error message.

Comment: Changing "ServerTokens Prod" to "ServerTokens Full" in httpd.conf solved my problem.

Comment: It's hard to overstate how assinine this entire situation is.  ServerTokens should be "prod" in production, to give away the least amount of info to attackers.  Fingerprinting the apache version through the HTTP headers will not work in properly configured environments.  Moreover, reducing the security so that you can get past an installer is obviously not best practices.  And final insult to injury, the instructions it prints are bunk, it sends you to edit httpd.conf which only is the right file if you compiled apache from source. Nonetheless this is the only solution to get it to install.